# High rate of Gen 1 garbage collections

Tags: asp.net, .net, performance, visual-studio-2010

I am profiling an application(using VS 2010) that is behaving badly in production. Once of the recommendations given by VS 2010 is:

> Relatively high rate of Gen 1 garbage collections is occurring. If, by
>   design, most of your program's data structures are allocated and
>   persisted for a long time, this is not ordinarily a problem. However,
>   if this behavior is unintended, your app may be pinning objects. If
>   you are not certain, you can gather .NET memory allocation data and
>   object lifetime information to understand the pattern of memory
>   allocation your application uses.

Searching on google gives the following link=> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee815714.aspx. Are there some obvious things that I can do to reduce this issue?I seem to be lost here.

> Double-click the message in the Errors List window to navigate to the
>   Marks View of the profiling data. Find the .NET CLR Memory# of Gen 0
>   Collections and .NET CLR Memory# of Gen 1 Collections columns.
>   Determine if there are specific phases of program execution where
>   garbage collection is occurring more frequently. Compare these values
>   to the % Time in GC column to see if the pattern of managed memory
>   allocations is causing excessive memory management overhead.
>
> To understand the application’s pattern of managed memory usage,
>   profile it again running a.NET Memory allocation profile and request
>   Object Lifetime measurements.
>
> For information about how to improve garbage collection performance,
>   see Garbage Collector Basics and Performance Hints on the Microsoft
>   Web site. For information about the overhead of automatic garbage
>   collection, see Large Object Heap Uncovered.

Comment: Maybe ou should first tell us whether this IS a problem. As the error said, this can happen naturally in a program that loads and buffers a lot of data. YOu totally fail to make a statement about this - and without knowing anything about your program, we are pretty much left to making uneducated guesses.

Comment: Um, he did say the application was suffering performance issues and that the profiler recommended this as one of the potential causes. I pretty clearly understood that he was asking for advice to better understand the recommendation and determine whether it was an actual issue with his application. It wasn't that bad of a post, at all.

Comment: Thanks Chris, TomTom,
Yes I was looking for advice on some suggestions to solve this performance problem. Perhaps I should have been more explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant line there is:

> To understand the application’s pattern of managed memory usage, profile it again running a.NET Memory allocation profile and request Object Lifetime measurements.

You need to understand how many objects are being allocated by your application and when, and how long they are alive for. You're probably allocating hundreds (or thousands!) of tiny objects inside a loop somewhere without really thinking about the consequences of reclaiming that memory when the references fall out of scope.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx states:

> Now that we have a basic model for how things are working, let's
>   consider some things that could go wrong that would make it slow. That
>   will give us a good idea what sorts of things we should try to avoid
>   to get the best performance out of the collector.
>
> **Too Many Allocations**
>
> This is really the most basic thing that can go wrong. Allocating new
>   memory with the garbage collector is really quite fast. As you can see
>   in Figure 2 above is all that needs to happen typically is for the
>   allocation pointer to get moved to create space for your new object on
>   the "allocated" side—it doesn't get much faster than that. However,
>   sooner or later a garbage collect has to happen and, all things being
>   equal, it's better for that to happen later than sooner. So you want
>   to make sure when you're creating new objects that it's really
>   necessary and appropriate to do so, even though creating just one is
>   fast.
>
> This may sound like obvious advice, but actually it's remarkably easy
>   to forget that one little line of code you write could trigger a lot
>   of allocations. For example, suppose you're writing a comparison
>   function of some kind, and suppose that your objects have a keywords
>   field and that you want your comparison to be case insensitive on the
>   keywords in the order given. Now in this case you can't just compare
>   the entire keywords string, because the first keyword might be very
>   short. It would be tempting to use String.Split to break the keyword
>   string into pieces and then compare each piece in order using the
>   normal case-insensitive compare. Sounds great right?
>
> Well, as it turns out doing it like that isn't such a good idea. You
>   see, String.Split is going to create an array of strings, which means
>   one new string object for every keyword originally in your keywords
>   string plus one more object for the array. Yikes! If we're doing this
>   in the context of a sort, that's a lot of comparisons and your
>   two-line comparison function is now creating a very large number of
>   temporary objects. Suddenly the garbage collector is going to be
>   working very hard on your behalf, and even with the cleverest
>   collection scheme there is just a lot of trash to clean up. Better to
>   write a comparison function that doesn't require the allocations at
>   all.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I will try that out and see how it goes.